# No handlers could be found for logger "universe" error message

Tags: openai-gym

I installed openai gym and universe and docker. When I ran the following code I got this error message:

No handlers could be found for logger "universe"

The code I ran is:

```
import gym     
import universe # register the universe environments

env = gym.make('flashgames.DuskDrive-v0')
env.configure(remotes=1) # downloads and starts a flashgames runtime
observation_n = env.reset()

while True:
        action_n = [[('KeyEvent', 'ArrowUp', True)] for ob in     observation_n] # your agent here
        observation_n, reward_n, done_n, info = env.step(action_n)
        env.render()
```

I believe it is env.configure(remotes=1), after researching for two days and tried numerous fixes that the other programer suggested, I still got this error message. Can someone help me please?
I am using terminal on OS X. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Can someone help me please? I am really stuck, any useful comment is very appreciated.